# Question regarding C++ Lists

Tags: c++

list dog;
       .............
       ............

So I added many dog objects to it.
   If I call `dog.pop_front();`

Does memory automatically gets deallocated ? For the object that I popped out ?

So If I call

```
list<Dog*> dog2;
dog2.push_back(dog.front());
```

and then I will call `dog.pop_front()` So this will work? I will assume Dog as type struct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You keep asking about this sequence:

```
list<Dog*> dog2;
dog2.push_back(dog.front());  // time 1
dog.pop_front();              // time 2
```

At time1, both `dog2` and `dog` have a pointer to the same object.

At time2, the pointer to that object is removed from `dog` and is only in `dog2`.

Assuming you originally created that object with `new Dog`, the object will not be freed until you explicitly free it by calling `delete ptr`

Answer (score 2):

The memory for the `Dog` object does *not* get deleted; this you'll have to do yourself.

However, the memory for the pointer, of type `Dog*`, as well as any "list node" object wrapped around it, *will* be automatically deleted by the `list` class.

Comment: So If I call list<Dog*> dog2; dog2.push_back(dog.front()); and then I will call dog.pop_front() So this will work? I will assume Dog as type struct.

Comment: @mousey If the 2 containers hold the same type, yes.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest a `list<shared_ptr<Dog> >` which takes care of deleting the dogs.

Answer (score 0):

No. You still have to deallocate it.

Answer (score 0):

No, you have to deallocate it yourself by calling delete, or free, depending how you allocated it.

Answer (score 0):

No. The memory for `Dog` object does not get deallocated. You'll have to make use of the `delete` operator to deallocate it.

Answer (score 0):

When you insert a `Dog*` into the list a copy of the *pointer* is created and insrted into the list. When you pop from the list memory allocated to this *pointer* is released. The memory allocated for the *Dog* object is not released as it was not allocated by the list. You have to release it yourself.

Comment: I didnt get you Naveen
so If I call list<Dog*> dog2;
dog2.push_back(dog.front());
and then I will call dog.pop_front()
So this will work?

Comment: @mousey: Yes that will work. Important thing to note here is the *copy* of the pointer is inserted into the list. When you do pop this copy is deleted.